# C# ASP.NET JQuery Script Not load After Deployed to IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I had a Master page with iFrame in it and 1 of the iFrame programs is using JQuery Ajax AutoComplete function for a TextBox. The program was running fine in VS2017 development. But the TextBox AutoComplete event not working after deployed to IIS 10. Did an Inspect on the iFrame page for the TextBox encountered that there is a missing function call in Event Listeners in Chrome debug section as show in attached screenshot. I had check all the included scripts link are able to view. Had try to searched around with many solutions but doesn't solve my problem. Any suggestion solutions or advices are welcome and thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtAccountNum").focus(function () {
        $("#txtAccountName").focus();
    });
});
var RootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

$(function () {
    $(".custSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: RootUrl + '/AutoComplete.asmx/SearchCustomer',
                data: "{ 'searchTxt': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            var v = i.item.value.split('-')[0];
            $('#txtAccountNum').val(v);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head runat="server">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Dashboard">
  <meta name="keyword" content="Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
  <title>Details</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../../Scripts/AutoCompleteSearch.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    
<section id="iframe-content-full">
      <section class="iframe-wrapper">
          <form class="cmxform form-horizontal style-form" id="form" runat="server">   
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">  
              <div class="row">
              <div class=" form">                    
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group ">
                          <asp:Label id="lblAccount" runat="server" class="control-label col-lg-2">Customer No </asp:Label> 
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountNum" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class=" col-lg-2" maxlength="50" Autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>                       
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Placeholder="Customer No" minlength="2" class="custSearch form-control" Autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>                            
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>                  
                  </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your DevTools and look for failed requests. As for the underlying cause, I'm assuming you're using an incorrectly configured Application Scope in IIS compared to your dev settings. ASP.NET requires an application-scope to be defined - this is not the same thing as a virtual-directory.

Comment: Dai! Tqvm for your clue... after checking on the network tab found that there was a broken link for the script reference. It's due to the https which in my code was http without the s. It's working well after changed all of them to https.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dai to provide advice.
The problem was due to the script src used in the program was not using secured https. The problem resolved after changed all the src link to "https".

Hope this will provide help to others as well to save their time. I had spend quite sometime to look for the solution on this issue.

Thanks again Dai.